# Who access DB faster - a Function or a Client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it faster to access a DB from a `Firebase Function` directly and then return a page,
or return a page right away, and access DB on client side using `JavaScript` ?

We need to get some data together with a page and we can return it via parameters on `Function` side, or return the simple page and ask the data on client side using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always be faster to access the DB from Firebase Function. However if you dump the whole table or list of items on client side and then run queries on that dataset then that will be faster.

But you mentioned "access DB on client side". If you mean access the DB which is on cloud then client side will have lots of overheads while talking to that DB.

You need to elaborate the scenario. There could be many possible answers depending on context.

Comment: Thanks! i simply talk about reading a Firebase data from a collection, for example a data from a document that i need to populate that page, so i can read it on Function and send it as parameters if its small enough, or return the page, and read it from the client.

Comment: I would suggest go with reading on Firebase function and send it back to the page. Once the data/collection is on the client side then you can parse it or run queries on it. Remember the less number of trips that your page makes to the server - the better it is. But dont send lots and lots of data back to client.

Comment: wait so a trip to the Function is faster or slower than a trip to the DB (from client side)?  also what if you have many parameters ?

Comment: trip to the function in your server side code is faster than a trip from Client to the DB. If you can share a sample then I will be able to help in better way.
Parameters -> you can send as many parameters to a server page as are required. However if it is too much data then your design is not correct. You need to stick to ACID principle: https://database.guide/what-is-acid-in-databases/

Comment: another good read about MVC and MVVM etc:
https://hackernoon.com/mvc-vs-mvvm-how-a-website-communicates-with-its-data-models-18553877bf7d

Comment: In my design, a client type a domain, then the Function need to decide what html to return by reading data base. but because it already access that DB, so it will return that html+parameters with the data (so client don't have to do it again). But sometimes the parameters to send are too much, like 3000 characters. The only solution i see is that the Function will access that DB record to read which html to return, then it return domain.com/someFolder/index, and then the client will ask the same record to read the data (instead of using parameters).